# Button works on emulator but not on device

Tags: java, android, button, sdk, onclick

I am creating an android app, it includes some buttons but one button works in emulator and in some old android versions (4.1.2, 4.4.2, 4.4.4) but not in 6.0 version. My min sdk version is 14 and targetsdk is 25. This button is in activity_main.xml

This is my button:

```
<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/content_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.example.besart.learngerman.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
         android:layout_height="5000dp"
         android:paddingLeft="5dp"
         android:paddingRight="5dp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:text="Alfabeti, ditet, numrat,..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#551905"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="alfabetiDheNumratClick" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.besart.learngerman">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

    </application>
```

Onclick method:

```
public void alfabetiDheNumratClick(View view){
    clickbutton.start();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlfabetiDheNumratActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Well what 'does not work'? And why are you posting manifest file?

Comment: The button works in emulator and in some old android versions(4.2.1, 4.2.2)but not in version 6.0 when I test it in actual devices.

Comment: What do you mean with 'does not work'? I asked that before.

Comment: It does not go to the activity it is supposed to go. It says "Unfortunately app has stopped". This only happens in real device, in emulator it goes to the that activity.

Comment: My god. And you are only telling that now!? You should have told that from the start. And why aren't you reacting to that answer that you got? You should comment there to tell if it helped.

Comment: `in emulator it goes to the that activity.`. So the function `alfabetiDheNumratClick()` is called! So the button works! Only the code in your buttons on click handler produces a crash! The subject of your post is completely wrong. Take that code out to see if your app still crases. After that add line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any activity registered in your manifest file.
Register your activities in manifest under

```
<application>
<activity android:name"your_activity_name"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Intent i = new Intent(Your_activity_name.this, AlfabetiDheNumratActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

OR

```
<Button
            android:text="Alfabeti, ditet, numrat,..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#551905"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="alfabetiDheNumratClick" />
```

But i'am not sure that it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem two days before but now issue is fixed. It was the problem of my compilesdkVersion. Actually my device was Lenovo API level 23
but in my gradle file my compileSdkVersion was 24 which i have changed to 23, and also i have changed the target sdk version to 24. Hope this helps.

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shiv.demoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 

    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

`
```